Robot localisation ROS2 outputs NaN, but covariance matrix looks good
I am trying to use this package: https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization
to fuse Odometry and Imu for a mobile robot, in ros2 humble.
here my .yaml file
ekf_filter_node:
    ros__parameters:
        frequency: 10.0
        #sensor_timeout: 0.1
        two_d_mode: true
        #transform_time_offset: 0.0
        #transform_timeout: 0.0
        print_diagnostics: true
        debug: true
        debug_out_file: /workspace/ros_ws/file.txt
        permit_corrected_publication: false
        publish_acceleration: false
        publish_tf: true

        map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
        odom_frame: odom            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
        base_link_frame: base_link  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
        world_frame: odom           # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified


        odom0: /odom
        odom0_config: [false,  false,  false,
                       false, false, false,
                       true, false, false,
                       false, false, true,
                       false, false, false]
        #odom0_queue_size: 2
        odom0_differential: false
        odom0_relative: false
        #odom0_pose_use_child_frame: false
        #odom0_pose_rejection_threshold: 5.0
        #odom0_twist_rejection_threshold: 1.0


        imu0: /imu/data/transformed
        imu0_config: [false,  false, false,
                      false,  false,  true,
                      false,  false, false,
                      false,  false,  true,
                      true,  false,  false]
        imu0_differential: false
        imu0_relative: false
        #imu0_queue_size: 5
        #imu0_pose_rejection_threshold: 0.8                 # Note the difference in parameter names
        #imu0_twist_rejection_threshold: 0.8                #
        #imu0_linear_acceleration_rejection_threshold: 0.8  #
        #imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

        #use_control: false
        #stamped_control: false
        #control_timeout: 0.2
        #control_config: [true, false, false, false, false, true]
        #acceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.4]
        #deceleration_limits: [1.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.5]
        #acceleration_gains: [0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9]
        #deceleration_gains: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

        process_noise_covariance: [0.05, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.05, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.06, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03, 0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.06, 0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.025, 0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.025, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.04, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.01, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.01, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.02, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01, 0.0,    0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01, 0.0,
                                   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,  0.015]

        initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9, 1e-9] 

Here the outputs of the sensors:
(/odom)
  stamp:
    sec: 1713370084
    nanosec: 381563756
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_link
pose:
  pose:
    position:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    orientation:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
  covariance:
  - 0.05
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.05
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.05
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.05
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.05
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.05
twist:
  twist:
    linear:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance:
  - 0.05
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.05
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.05
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.05
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.05
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.05
  --- 

(/imu/data/transformed)
  stamp:
    sec: 1713370191
    nanosec: 991578738
  frame_id: imu_link
orientation:
  x: -0.003763240087306349
  y: 0.004439437789912494
  z: 0.010076406475401546
  w: 0.9999322954323944
orientation_covariance:
- 0.025
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.025
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.025
angular_velocity:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0023387372493743896
angular_velocity_covariance:
- 0.01
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.01
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.01
linear_acceleration:
  x: -0.1214335709810257
  y: -0.058592066168785095
  z: 9.80672836303711
linear_acceleration_covariance:
- 0.01
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.01
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.01
---

Here is the output
(/odometry/filtered)
  stamp:
    sec: 1713370236
    nanosec: 897228438
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_link
pose:
  pose:
    position:
      x: .nan
      y: .nan
      z: .nan
    orientation:
      x: .nan
      y: .nan
      z: .nan
      w: .nan
  covariance:
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
twist:
  twist:
    linear:
      x: .nan
      y: .nan
      z: .nan
    angular:
      x: .nan
      y: .nan
      z: .nan
  covariance:
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
  - .nan
--- 

error msg:
[ekf_node-3] [ERROR] [1713437636.760393768] [ekf_filter_node]: Critical Error, NaNs were detected in the output state of the filter. This was likely due to poorly coniditioned process, noise, or sensor covariances.
[ekf_node-3] Error:   TF_NAN_INPUT: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "base_link" from authority "Authority undetectable" because of a nan value in the transform (-nan -nan -nan) (-nan -nan -nan -nan)
[ekf_node-3]          at line 235 in ./src/buffer_core.cpp
[ekf_node-3] Error:   TF_DENORMALIZED_QUATERNION: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "base_link" from authority "Authority undetectable" because of an invalid quaternion in the transform (-nan -nan -nan -nan)

Any ideas why this is happening ?

Does it go to NaN right away, or does it take some time? Let's look at your config:
two_d_mode: true
This means you want the filter to operate in 2D. So you need to provide:

X position and/or X velocity
Y position and/or Y velocity
Yaw and/or yaw velocity

Now let's look at your sensor config:
        odom0_config: [false,  false,  false,
                       false, false, false,
                       true, false, false,
                       false, false, true,
                       false, false, false]

You are fusing X velocity and yaw velocity from your odometry.
        imu0_config: [false,  false, false,
                      false,  false,  true,
                      false,  false, false,
                      false,  false,  true,
                      true,  false,  false]

You are fusing yaw and yaw velocity from your IMU. Also, I don't see any static transform provided from imu_link to base_link. You'll need that.
As you can see, you are not providing any reference for Y or Y velocity. Without this, the covariance for the Y dimension will start to explode, which will in turn cause the covariance of all correlated dimensions to explode, and you'll eventually get NaN values.
If it were me, I'd fuse the Y velocity from my odometry. 0 values are perfectly valid if your robot can't move sideways.
